# echo message if no records found from database

Tags: php

I have created a search box that will pull certain parameters from the MySQL database. What code would I need to embed into the following code if no parameters occurred causing the echo text to inform the user that no matching parameters could be great.

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("store_location");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_location where store_name like '%$term%' or     address like '%$term%' or city like '%$term%' or state like '%$term%' or zip like     '%$term%' or phone like '%$term%' or fax like '%$term%' or email like '%$term%' or url     like '%$term%' ");

echo '<h1>Search Results:</h1>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo 'Store Name: '.$row['store_name'];
echo '<br/> Address: '.$row['address'];
echo '<br/> City: '.$row['city'];
echo '<br/> State: '.$row['state'];
echo '<br/> Zip: '.$row['zip'];
echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['phone'];
echo '<br/> Fax: '.$row['fax'];
echo '<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</a>';
echo '<br/> URL: <a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a>';
echo '<br/><br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Check [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows).

Comment: where you want to redirect if records doesn't found ?

Comment: Please sip using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. They are old and deprecated. See that red box? Please switch to the new and safer `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

Add this before the `while...` line:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) echo "<p>No matches</p>";
```

[docs](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows)

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of records from a table, you can try following code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from table_name");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result['total'];
if( $result['total']==0)
{
echo "no records is found";
}else{
echo"numbers of records is=".$result['total'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo 'Store Name: '.$row['store_name'];
        echo '<br/> Address: '.$row['address'];
        echo '<br/> City: '.$row['city'];
        echo '<br/> State: '.$row['state'];
        echo '<br/> Zip: '.$row['zip'];
        echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['phone'];
        echo '<br/> Fax: '.$row['fax'];
        echo '<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</a>';
        echo '<br/> URL: <a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}else{
    echo 'No results found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']); // sanitize input!
if ($sql = mysql_query('...')) { // mysql_* functions are deprecated, consider mysqli instead
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo "<h1>$count Result" . ($count == 1 ? '' : 's') . ' Found' . ($count ? ':' : '') . '</h1>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '...';
    }
}
```